# Is it possible to open a <form> tag in one <div> element then close it in another <div> element>

Tags: html, forms

I was wondering if I can do something like this:

```
<div>
    <form>
        <input type="text">
</div>
<div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

This is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. My intent is to have the button to submit the form in a separate div from the form itself. I know I can do this with javascript, but someone I know says I can do this instead.

Comment: Why don't you [validate it](http://validator.w3.org/) and find out?

Comment: Why do you even want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

move your form tags outside of the div tags

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to properly close your tags. Please use a markup validator: http://validator.w3.org

Answer (score 1):

you need to close the tags prperly but if want to submit the form out side div you can do it like this:

```
<div>
     <form name="form1">
       <input type="text">
     </form>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" onclick="document.form1.submit();" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just wrap the entire set of divs in the form tags and it would probably make more sense that way.